# Collection style web game

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, web

I'm attempting to program my first web game. My question is about the technologies I would need to use. I want to allow users to **collect items** and **save progress** in the game. I'm working on learning HTML, CSS, and Javascript. It looks like I'll need a server side language such as MySQL to save user data, or maybe jquery is a better choice. Can someone please help point me in the right direction on this? Thanks.

Comment: This site is for *specific* programming issues. As it stands, your question is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: `MySQL` is a `RDBMS`. Its language is `SQL`. `jQuery` is a library for `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to make sure you're clear with the components before jumping in and trying to code stuff up or think about implementation.

Some shallow tips:

`MySQL` is a `RDBMS` or a Relational Database Management System. As a Database, it sits on a machine (could be your computer or a server somewhere), and applications connect with it and make transactions with it using the `SQL` database language.

MySQL is for keeping persistent state for a large amount of data.

`jQuery` is a `library` for JavaScript. It basically decreases the lines of code you need to write for JavaScript, and makes it easier to do common things in JavaScript (it is NOT a framework like Angular or Backbone. jQuery is a library -- a bunch of built in functions basically).

jQuery is for making things happen in the browser, often from user input/interaction.

So it doesn't make sense to ask if MySQL *or* JavaScript is the better choice. They have very different roles/responsibilities, and exist at separate levels of a web app's infrastructure.